# How to call prototype function in HTML element on some event?

Tags: javascript

I have calendar constructor function and two prototype functions in first prototype function I am creating div element and creating it's attribute `ondragstart` and I want to call another prototype function on in it's second argument `var that = this; that.drag(event)`, but when it renders it shows `<div ondragstart="that.drag(event)">` console gives error `that is not function`. How can I call prototype function in this situation? please explain with example, thanks.

```
 calendar.prototype.tbl = function(){
 var that = this;
 var evDiv = document.createElement('div');     
 evDiv.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
 evDiv.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'that.drag(event)');
 }

 calendar.prototype.drag = function(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `setAttribute`. Do not use event listener attributes. Do not use code inside strings.

Comment: Do not use event handlers (prefixed with `on`). Use event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
calendar.prototype.tbl = function() {
    var that = this;
    var evDiv = document.createElement('div');

    evDiv.draggable = true;
    evDiv.addEventListener('dragstart', that.drag);
};

calendar.prototype.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
};
```